# Including Files in Parent Folders PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

In my root html directory, i have an installation of SMF, and also an installation of CodeIgniter.  I am making a custom library of the SMF SSI for use in CI, but I'm having trouble including the SSI.php file.  This is what my html root directory looks like:

```
- html/root
  /forums (html/forums)
      -SSI.php
  /application
      /libraries
          -SMF.php(html/application/libraries)
  /system
```

So in the file application/libraries/smf.php, how would I include SSI.php?  This is what I am using, but it says file not found

`include('.../forums/SSI.php');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your file into `html/application/libraries` folder and the file you want to include is into `html/forums` folder you can use below code to include.

```
../../forums/SSI.php
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the base directory you use one of these:

```
  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

or:

```
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is available in the library or not but FCPATH normally points to your CI root directory and APPPATH normally points to your application directory. Hope that helps somewhat, those are set in the CI root index.php file you can try echoing them out to see if they got to the library if not add a setter inside of it like

```
/**
 * Storage holder for the include files paths, is changed by $this->include_file()
 *
 * @access protected
 * 
 * @var string
 */
protected $_path;

/**
 * Sets the path for include files.
 *
 * @access private
 * 
 * @param string $path Path of files to include.
 */
private function set_path($path)
{
  $this->_path = $path;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Includes file.
 * 
 * @param  string $file Filename to include
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function include_file($file)
{
  include($this->_path . $file);
}
```

Then set it from the CI scope with

```
<?php
  $this->library->set_path(FCPATH);
  $this->library->include_file('SI.php');
```

Something like that might work if I understand what your looking for correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's two periods, not one. One represents current directory, two represents parent, and any others represent a true directory:

```
require_once('../{URL}');
```

Comment: Or, if you need to back up two directory levels, `../../{URL}`.  The `../` can be stacked.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use absolute path.

```
include __DIR__ . '/../../forums/SSI.php';                             // php version >= 5.3 
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../forums/SSI.php'              //  php version < 5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
include_once FCPATH."forums/SSI.php";
```

FCPATH is root folder of CodeIgniter Installation